# Decide whether or not the matrices A and B are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Decide whether or not the matrices A and B are similar.
A=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\2&0&2\\3&0&3\end{bmatrix}

B=
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\2&2&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}

I found that the characteristic matrices are different between both matrices.
The equation for A is (1-λ)(3-λ) and the equation for B is (1-λ)(2-λ)(1-λ).

Since the characteristic equations are different doesn't that mean the eigenbases are also different, therefore they aren't similar?

I think I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: well your equation for the characteristic polynomial for $A$ can't be right, because it's the wrong degree.

Comment: It looks like you are finding the characteristic equations by taking the product of the diagonal elements of either $A-I\lambda$ or $B-I\lambda$, but this isn't quite right. The characteristic equation should come from the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of $A-I\lambda$ or $B-I\lambda$.

Comment: $A$ has rank 1, $B$ has rank 2, hence, not similar.

Answer (score 0):

Similar matrices have the same  polynomial and hence the same characteristic roots .

Note that $A$ has  $0,0,4$ as characteristic  values whereas $B$ has $0,1,3$ has characteristic values.

So not similar